# finding names who've borrowed books from publisher

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm working on a homework assignment, and I'm just plain stuck on this one.

The structure I'm given is this:

```
member(memb_no, name, age)

book(isbn, title, authors, publisher)

borrowed(memb_no, isbn, date)
```

The question is basically to return the table of names that have borrowed ALL books of a given publisher (McGraw-Hill).

I just did the previous question, which was the same except ANY book from that publisher, but I just can't think of how I would check to see if I member has borrowed ALL the books from a given publisher, using just MySQL.

Could anyone suggest how to go about solving this?  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks p.campbell... didn't know I could do that, much easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

I won't give you an answer, but I will suggest some topics to check out.

Look into these SQL clauses:

- JOIN
- COUNT
- GROUP BY
- HAVING

Also explore the concept of subqueries within the select clause.

Happy hunting!

([A quick general SQL resource](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/) which describes a few of those terms)
([The relevant MySQL documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html))

Comment: More tips :). Your query's workflow should be something like: For each member select the amount of DISTINCT books borrowed from 'McGraw-Hill' and compare that to the total amount of McGraw-Hill's books.

Comment: you can "select (subquery) AS totalCount"

Comment: So start with a subquery of something like
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book WHERE publisher = 'McGraw-Hill'`?

Comment: Yes, but you need to make sure that you're counting DISTINCT isbns for each person. Keep at it. There's a couple of different approaches to do this one.

Comment: James -- out of curiosity, did you set up a test server for this?  It is much easier to explore queries if you can try running them.

Comment: Sorry to hear you've thrown in the towel.  If you want to try again just be sure to set up a SQL server of your own to play with these concepts!  SQL is actually a lot of fun, but I don't think it's easy to learn through theory or psets; you have to get your hands dirty.